# Is Pareto efficiency (Pareto Optimal) a part of Operation Research?

Tags: operations-research

I know that Pareto efficiency (Pareto Optimal) is an economic concept that helps for multi-criteria decision making process. My doubt is whether any decision process is a part of Operation Research. In fact, I know that OR is a discipline that deals with the application of advanced analytical methods to help make better decisions. Could someone please tell me whether Pareto Optimality is a part of OR or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have seen many research papers in OR using Pareto optimality. It is used whenever a multi-criteria optimization is at stake. What exactly do you know about operations research? Do you need some kind of "tour guide"?

Comment: @vincent..Thanks. I took the course Operation research, but this concept was new for me. When I read some papers on Pairwise Comparison of Matrices I got Pareto Optimal and was confused.